# Finding more solutions given 2 solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let C be a 3 × 3 matrix, different from 0, such that the equation

Cx= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\-1 \end{bmatrix}

has both \begin{bmatrix}3 \\1 \\4 \end{bmatrix} and

\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\\3 \end{bmatrix}

as solutions. Write down two further solutions of the equation.

I'm having trouble how to solve this question, can anyone please help.

Comment: Hint: if $\,C x_1 = y\,$ and $\,C x_2 = y\,$ then $\,C (x_1-x_2) = \dots\,$

Comment: =0?................................

Comment: That's genius, thanks! How could I've not thought of that

Comment: So any scalar multiple will be a solution?

Comment: No, but $\,C\left(\lambda(x_1-x_2)\right)=0\,$ for any scalar $\,\lambda\,$, so $\,C\left(x_1+\lambda(x_1-x_2)\right)=\dots\,$

Comment: Could we use $$C(x\_2+\lambda (x\_1 - x\_2))$$, though?

Comment: Yes, that works, too.